# Google Ads to BigQuery Data AuthorizationError.USER_PERMISSION_DENIED [...success error success error error...]

Tags: google-bigquery, data-transfer

I am having the following problem: I have set up Google Ads data transfer to Bigquery, it used to work fine for about a month, then I got some `AuthorizationError.USER_PERMISSION_DENIED` error.
Now, I have seen [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/common-errors#AuthorizationError.USER_PERMISSION_DENIED) that potential cause might be

> "The link between the manager and client account was removed."

but that does not explain why transfer schedule had successful runs after first (few) errors, and then stopped working again. Can anyone shed some light on this, please? How can I fix the problem?

Here are screenshots of [run history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TER0M.jpg), [more run history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKyKZ.png) and [transfer configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRJ1j.png)
P.S. Start date was changed to "December 1" instead of early November after I rescheduled time.